# HTTPService from an VO is doing problems

Tags: actionscript-3, httpservice

I'm fairly new to AS and I have some problems using the HTPService from a VO I created.
here is my code:

```
package ValueObjects
{
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

    [Bindable]
    public class Indicator
    {
        protected var service:HTTPService;

        public function Indicator( id:int , name:String , group_id:int, alias:String)
        {
        }   

        public function getfields():void
        {
            this.service = new HTTPService();
            service.url = "Here is my url - i've tested it and its working"
            trace(service.url);
            service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, createFields);
            service.send();
        }

        public function createFields(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            trace("got here");
            service.removeEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, createFields);
        }

    }
}
```

my problem is that for some reason I don't get the result. not getting the trace "got here" - it seems that the createFields function isn't invoked.
Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks in advance

Ravid

Edit:
Some more information, my network monitor doesn't show the request or the response, there is no result event dispatched(is it possible? ?) or at list a one that i managed to fins with the debugger
Also, if I change the `service.send();`  into a `var data:AsyncToken = service.send();` and than debug the data var its "Result" property stays null all the time.

i'm sending the request to my localhost, i've checked that my url is working, other requests from a mxml file went ok without problem. 
Any ideas? ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

Apparently the problem was on the server side.

There was a type in the generated xml and flex's "event.fault.faultDetail" property was not not set therefor i didn't get the error.

use "event.fault.faultString" fault string instead.